# Редиректы в htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

Всем привет, подскажите как сделать редирект "без последнего слеша" с "последним слешем", а так же "/index.php" в "/". Сделал так, но почему-то не работает

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ \/index\.php\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http:\/\/%{HTTP_HOST}\/ [R=301,QSA,L]

php_flag zlib.output_compression On
php_value zlib.output_compression_level 5
```

Comment: Глянь здесь может чего нибудь полезного найдешь [трюки с файлом .htaccess][1]


  [1]: http://ruseller.com/search.php?s=htaccess

Comment: а в целом правильно же у меня написано?

Comment: Если не хочешь что бы адрес был 

    http://www.mysite.ru/index.php

То просто не надо указывать в ссылке index.php пиши просто

    <a href="/" >Главная</>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После `$1` допишите слэш:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ru/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

А для `index.php` строку надо перенести перед предыдущей, что-то вроде этого:

```
RewriteRule /index\.php$     /
```

Это будет менять конец строки `/blabla/index.php` на `/blabla/`, но я не проверял. В итоге должно быть примерно так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ \/index\.php\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule /index\.php$     /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ru/$1/ [R=301,L]
```